# Assets in Yii Framework

Tags: php, yii

Can somebody  explain in brief the use of assets folder in yii framework. I am new to yii framework

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Many newcomers ask: "What do we do with the assets folder?", and the answer is "Mostly nothing".

- It's important that the directory be writable by the webserver user so that Yii can publish the resources there when needed.
- When a project has multiple versions (production, testing, development, etc.) do not copy the assets/ folders from one area to another; allow Yii to deploy them automatically in each area.
- Do not manually edit any file under assets/ - if you have a real need to make a change, find the publishing module, edit the source, delete the subfolder under assets/, and let Yii re-publish the updated files.
- Do not reference names under the assets/ folder directly (say, to get at some other module's assets). If you need to use that
- Do not add the contents of the assets/ folder to any source-code control system; these files have master source in other places.
- It is safe to delete everything under assets/. Yii will re-publish the assets if they are not found under assets/.

[Additional info](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/148/understanding-assets)

Comment: Yii framework uses assets folder to make sure that same named resource file will not conflict each other.
ie if you have downloaded two extension but both have same named style.css file and you use those extension on same page so now style.css file will conflict each other , now assets directory comes on picture to solve conflict issue

Answer (score 0):

Yii makes assets accessible by Web clients, so the goal of copying assets to a Web-accessible directory is fulfilled and returns the corresponding URL for accessing them.

Read it from http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CAssetManager